# Json and deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I have an issue to find the type of an object. I'm using MailChimp API and tried a couple of different scenarios. One of them is to send an incorrect email address (blablagmail.com, @ is missing).

I want to deserialize the json to be able to create a string with all the errors. Here the json with only the two properties that bug me:

```
"error_count":1,
"errors":[
    {
      "email_address":"blablagmail.com",
      "error":"Please provide a valid email address."
    }
 ],
```

Basically, what I try to do is to is to create an unique string with all the erros for my logger. Something like:

errors = "email_address:blablagmail.com, error:Please provide a valid email address."

I tried to cast `errors` as `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` but it doesn't work. The thing is the properties (`email_address` or `error`) can have a different name depending on the error.

Here the class I've created to deserialize the json

```
public class MailChimpResponse
{
    public object[] new_members { get; set; }
    public object[] updated_members { get; set; }
    public object[] errors { get; set; }
    public int total_created { get; set; }
    public int total_updated { get; set; }
    public int error_count { get; set; }
} 

MailChimpResponse obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MailChimpResponse>(response);
```

Now if error_count > 0 I want to log the errors so I would like to create a genreic function to convert this array of object (`object[] errors`) to a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by "I tried to cast error as `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` but it doesn't work."? Ideally show the code you tried, and exactly what happened. Do you have to use the `JavaScriptSerializer`, or are you able to use Json.NET?

Comment: Also, what would you want to happen if you had multiple errors? If you could provide sample input and output for that, that would be useful.

Comment: Is that exactly how you see two properties or do they have curly braces at the beginning and at the end?

Comment: Is this the complete json ? Because it's not a valid Json.

Comment: Quick tip: http://json2csharp.com ;)

Comment: I've updated my post. I can't use json.net or add any other references.

Comment: @Daisy That the thing, I want to create a function to take each property and value and create a unique string. In my example, I've two properties and two value so the string must be: str = "prop1:value1, prop2:val2, etc..."

Comment: @AD8 In my original post, this is the json but when I'm debugging, I see every item of errors like this : {[email_address, blablagmail.com]} , {[error, Please provide a valid email address.]}

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)?

Comment: @TylerDurden: But you've got an *array* - so there could be multiple objects. Would you want that to be multiple strings? One string over multiple lines? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simulated your scenario in a Console application. Output of this sample is as you mentioned in your question. I used `JavaScriptSerializer`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"error_count\":1,\"errors\":[{\"email_address\":\"blablagmail.com\",\"error\":\"Please provide a valid email address.\"}]}";

        MailChimpResponse obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MailChimpResponse>(json);

        if (obj != null && obj.error_count > 0 && obj.errors!=null)
        {
            string errorString = "";

            foreach (var error in obj.errors)
            {
                var casting = (Dictionary<string,object>)error;

                errorString = string.Join(",", casting.Select(x => x.Key + ":" + x.Value).ToArray());
            }

            Console.WriteLine(errorString);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MailChimpResponse
{
    public object[] new_members { get; set; }
    public object[] updated_members { get; set; }
    public object[] errors { get; set; }
    public int total_created { get; set; }
    public int total_updated { get; set; }
    public int error_count { get; set; }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

`email_address:blablagmail.com, error:Please provide a valid email address.`

Comment: Thanks man, my error was to use a Dictionary<string,string> instead of <string,object> so the cast didn't work..